# Improving edge detection for bubble sheet grader in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

[image]I am trying to create a bubble sheet scanner but unfortunately it does not detect the image if the bubble sheet picture is captured by a mobile phone, maybe due to the thresholding and edge detection or due to the resolution of the picture unfortunately I've had little to no progress solving this issue. Any help or tips on how to solve this issue would be appreciated,

here is the code

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


ANSWER_KEY = {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1}

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, blur it
# slightly, then find edges
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 75, 200)

# find contours in the edge map, then initialize
# the contour that corresponds to the document
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
docCnt = None

# ensure that at least one contour was found
if len(cnts) > 0:
    # sort the contours according to their size in
    # descending order
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    # loop over the sorted contours
    for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

        # if our approximated contour has four points,
        # then we can assume we have found the paper
        if len(approx) == 4:
            docCnt = approx
            break

# apply a four point perspective transform to both the
# original image and grayscale image to obtain a top-down
# birds eye view of the paper
paper = four_point_transform(image, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))
warped = four_point_transform(gray, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))

# apply Otsu's thresholding method to binarize the warped
# piece of paper
thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize
# the list of contours that correspond to questions
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
questionCnts = []

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour, then use the
    # bounding box to derive the aspect ratio
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / float(h)

    # in order to label the contour as a question, region
    # should be sufficiently wide, sufficiently tall, and
    # have an aspect ratio approximately equal to 1
    if w >= 20 and h >= 20 and ar >= 0.9 and ar <= 1.1:
        questionCnts.append(c)

# sort the question contours top-to-bottom, then initialize
# the total number of correct answers
questionCnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts,
    method="top-to-bottom")[0]
correct = 0

# each question has 5 possible answers, to loop over the
# question in batches of 5
for (q, i) in enumerate(np.arange(0, len(questionCnts), 5)):
    # sort the contours for the current question from
    # left to right, then initialize the index of the
    # bubbled answer
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts[i:i + 5])[0]
    bubbled = None

    # loop over the sorted contours
    for (j, c) in enumerate(cnts):
        # construct a mask that reveals only the current
        # "bubble" for the question
        mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 255, -1)

        # apply the mask to the thresholded image, then
        # count the number of non-zero pixels in the
        # bubble area
        mask = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask=mask)
        total = cv2.countNonZero(mask)

        # if the current total has a larger number of total
        # non-zero pixels, then we are examining the currently
        # bubbled-in answer
        if bubbled is None or total > bubbled[0]:
            bubbled = (total, j)

    # initialize the contour color and the index of the
    # *correct* answer
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    k = ANSWER_KEY[q]

    # check to see if the bubbled answer is correct
    if k == bubbled[1]:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        correct += 1

    # draw the outline of the correct answer on the test
    cv2.drawContours(paper, [cnts[k]], -1, color, 3)

# grab the test taker
score = (correct / 5.0) * 100
print("[INFO] score: {:.2f}%".format(score))
cv2.putText(paper, "{:.2f}%".format(score), (10, 30),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Exam", paper)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Not reproducible without the images.

Comment: show us the pictures! =)

Comment: I have updated the post with the image in question, it should detect the edges and contours but it always fails to find them and as such doesn't even reach the correcting stage